# Importing .obj files with textures in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to render a 3D model .obj file downloaded from the web but I'm having issues with applying the textures to the model. .mlt, .obj and texture .jpg files are all in the same folder (e.g. car.obj, car.mtl, car.jpg, carDark.jpg).

Are the textures supposed to be applied automatically by Model I/O? How am I supposed to use Model I/O to import textures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the file path to the `.mtl` file in the `.obj` file?
If this path is incorrect then the materials will not load.
OBJ and MTL files are text files so you can use a text editor to open them.
The path to the `.mtl` file should be at the top of the `.obj` file:

```
mtllib mymtlfile.mtl
```

If they are in the same folder you can just strip the path.

If this path is okay then you should check the paths to the textures in the `.mtl` file. Look for lines starting with `map_`. For instance:

```
map_Kd mydiffusetexture.png
map_Ka /path/to/myambienttexture.tga
map_bump mybumptexture.jpg
```

If you strip all the paths then the file import should work.

Comment: If you are working on a structure with Folder containing Textures you can simply write "Folder-Name/textureName.jpg" inside mtl file as defining path. It will update the models look when restarting Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Add your textures images files in art.scnassets

[image]

Select your scene and select your textures in Material properties

[image]

Comment: The 3D files are downloaded at runtime from a server, so it is not possible to do this in Xcode.